# Get indices of disordered list python

Tags: python, sorting

I have two lists (actually, two dataframe columns). They have the same elements but one list is disordered. I would like to get the indices of the disordered list corresponding to the ordered list. Is there an easy way to do this?

I.E. list1[indices] == list2

I need to obtain the indices variable.

Comment: Consider also adding the code you've done so far with a data sample.

Comment: What does *"indices of the disordered list corresponding to the ordered list"* mean? Can you show an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C8H10N42's answer has time complexity of O(n^2), it will take a long time on big lists. Each call to index() is O(n), and it is called n times.

If you need better performance you can use this O(n) solution instead:

```
l1 = ['a','b','c','d']
l2 = ['c','d','b','a']
indices = {val: i for i, val in enumerate(l1)}

[indices[x] for x in l2]
```

Creating the dictionary is O(n), then you can replace the O(n) index() call with O(1) dict access. So the complexity is O(n) + O(n) instead of O(n^2).

If you try both with different list sizes you will see the bigger the list, the worse index() performs in comparison:

```
from timeit import timeit
from random import shuffle

for n in range(0, 50, 5):
    l1 = list(range(n))
    l2 = l1[:]
    shuffle(l2)

    t1 = timeit('indices = {val: i for i, val in enumerate(l1)}; [indices[x] for x in l2]', 'from __main__ import l1, l2')
    t2 = timeit('[l1.index(x) for x in l2]', 'from __main__ import l1, l2')
    print("n = %s, t1 = %s, t2 = %s, t2/t1 = %s" % (n, t1, t2, t2/t1))
```

Result:

```
n = 0, t1 = 0.410041093826, t2 = 0.0470049381256, t2/t1 = 0.114634700847
n = 5, t1 = 1.01210093498, t2 = 0.980098009109, t2/t1 = 0.96837970921
n = 10, t1 = 1.70017004013, t2 = 2.06220698357, t2/t1 = 1.21294160872
n = 15, t1 = 2.12121200562, t2 = 3.28132796288, t2/t1 = 1.54691183823
n = 20, t1 = 2.64426398277, t2 = 4.81948184967, t2/t1 = 1.82261751515
n = 25, t1 = 3.42534303665, t2 = 6.57365703583, t2/t1 = 1.9191237098
n = 30, t1 = 3.95739603043, t2 = 8.52685213089, t2/t1 = 2.15466232475
n = 35, t1 = 4.24842405319, t2 = 10.8080809116, t2/t1 = 2.54402121265
n = 40, t1 = 4.75647592545, t2 = 13.3403339386, t2/t1 = 2.80466760427
n = 45, t1 = 5.33353281021, t2 = 15.6205620766, t2/t1 = 2.92874584865
```

Comment: @jbch: It's not very fair to compare your answer to list comprehension-based solution proposed by @C8H10N4O2, which is slower than the `map`-based solution I proposed. Using your code, my solution is still about 30 times faster for n=45

Comment: @sciroccorics I used list comprehensions for both. If you switch to map for both, you get the same ratios more or less.  On my machine and Python version anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`list.index()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_index.htm) inside a list comprehension:

```
l1 = ['a','b','c','d']
l2 = ['c','d','b','a']

[l1.index(x) for x in l2] #[2, 3, 1, 0]
```

If you are trying to do this in a `DataFrame`, you can convert from `np.array` to `list` and back, as in:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'v1':np.array(l1), 'v2':np.array(l2)})

df['index_of_v2_in_v1'] = np.array([list(df['v1']).index(x) for x in list(df['v2'])])

df
# Result:
#   v1 v2  index_of_v2_in_v1
# 0  a  c                  2
# 1  b  d                  3
# 2  c  b                  1
# 3  d  a                  0
```

If you are **100% sure** that List 1 is sorted already (as your question suggests) you can simply use `np.argsort(l2)` on the list or array, as in:

```
np.argsort(df['v2'])
# Returns:
#0    3
#1    2
#2    0
#3    1
#Name: v2, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you, I was hoping a numpy based solution though, to avoid loops. I will wait a little longer and mark this as accepted if that other option doesn't come up.

Answer (score 1):

Using `map` is about 3.6 times faster than list comprehension in this example:

```
from timeit import timeit

l1 = ['a','b','c','d']
l2 = ['c','d','b','a']

t1 = timeit('map(lambda e: l1.index(e), l2)', globals=globals())
t2 = timeit('[l1.index(x) for x in l2]', globals=globals())
print("t1 = %s, t2 = %s, t2/t1 = %s" % (t1, t2, t2/t1))
```

Result:

```
t1 = 0.32407195774213654, t2 = 1.162188749526786, t2/t1 = 3.586205846454439
```

---

EDIT : Additional comparison including the solution proposed by @jbch :

```
from timeit import timeit
from random import shuffle

for n in range(10, 70, 10):
    l1 = list(range(n))
    l2 = l1[:]
    shuffle(l2)

    t1 = timeit('indices = {val: i for i, val in enumerate(l1)}; [indices[x] for x in l2]', globals=globals())
    t2 = timeit('[l1.index(x) for x in l2]', globals=globals())
    t3 = timeit('map(lambda e: l1.index(e), l2)', globals=globals())
    print("n = %d, t1 = %g, t2 = %g, t3 = %g" % (n, t1, t2, t3))
```

Result:

```
n = 10, t1 = 3.25064, t2 = 3.70473, t3 = 0.339757
n = 20, t1 = 5.01145, t2 = 9.22295, t3 = 0.341116
n = 30, t1 = 7.18546, t2 = 16.6379, t3 = 0.344537
n = 40, t1 = 8.96271, t2 = 26.0522, t3 = 0.336952
n = 50, t1 = 11.0635, t2 = 37.7291, t3 = 0.341935
n = 60, t1 = 12.6453, t2 = 51.1519, t3 = 0.350777
```

Comment: You have to use map for both if you want to make that comparison. Replace `[indices[x] for x in l2]` by `map(lambda x: indices[x], l2)` on line 9. I don't know why list comprehensions are so slow on your system, I only see a 20% difference on mine (Python 3.5 on Windows).

Comment: I'm really puzzled as to why you see such a big performance difference between map and list comps. What version of Python and OS do you have?

Comment: @jbch: I use Python 3.6 on Windows 10. Moreover, my benchmark was done on a pretty old laptop. I'm on vacation this week, but I will try on some other computers a work next week.